# Determine which page a :delete request is coming from

Tags: ruby-on-rails, request

I was wondering how to determine what page a :delete request is coming from? For example, I have a wall post that appears on both a user’s home page and show page. When a user deletes a post from the home page, I would want the user to be redirected to the home page while if he deleted it from his show (profile) page, I would want the user to get redirected back there. The issue is though, I’m having trouble differentiating where its coming from.

I understand that in :delete requests, you can't pass in hidden values since it’s not a :post. I’ve tried checking the params, but they all wind up being the same. They have the same :method, :controller, and :action i.e.

```
{"_method"=>"delete", "authenticity_token"=>"xNsfq27sBrpssTO8sk0aAzzIu8cvnFJEZ30c17Q+BCM=",
"action"=>"destroy", "controller"=>"pub_messages", "id"=>"33"}
```

In my destroy action, I have:

```
def destroy
    @pub_message = PubMessage.find_by_id(params[:id])
    @pub_message.destroy
    redirect_to user_path(@pub_message.to_id)
end
```

But instead of always redirecting back to the user_path, I want to redirect to the root_path but just can't figure out when the user is issuing the destroy action while on the home page or not.

Where I show the delete option in my view is...

```
<% if current_user == feed_item.user or current_user == feed_item.to %>
   <%= link_to "delete", feed_item,     method: :delete,
                                        confirm: "You sure?",
                                        title: feed_item.content %>
<% end %>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `redirect_to :back`, as described [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to). That will take you back to the HTTP_REFERER from the request.

Answer (score 2):

```
redirect_to request.referer
```

Or

```
redirect_to :back
```

Will redirect you to the previous page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `redirect_to :back` to use the Referer.

If you fear that many of your visitors' browser don't fill the Referer header in requests, you can deal with a from params :

```
def destroy
  @pub_message = PubMessage.find_by_id(params[:id])
  @pub_message.destroy
  redirect_to user_path(@pub_message.to_id) and return if params[:from] == "profile"
  redirect_to home_path # no if to fallback
end

<% if current_user == feed_item.user or current_user == feed_item.to %>
  <%= link_to "delete", feed_path(feed_item, from: "profile"), method: :delete,
                                                               confirm: "You sure?",
                                                               title: feed_item.content %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You *can* pass in extra parameters:

```
<%= link_to "delete", feed_item_path(feed_item, :foo => :bar),
                 method: :delete,
                 confirm: "You sure?",
                 title: feed_item.content %>
```

and then use those to decide where you are redirecting to.

If you don't like having those as query parameters, then you could setup different routes that would pass those parameters in for you.